# AutoHotKey Format Time

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to format 24 hour time like this.

If I type "1930+" → 19:30

If I type "0630+" → 06:30

Basically when it reads a "+" at the end of a number 0-9 then it adds a " : " two places backwards. Just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; *: An ending character is not required 
; ?: The hotstring will be triggered even when it is inside another word 

#Hotstring * ? 

::0+::
::1+::
; ...
::9+::
    PriorKey := SubStr(A_PriorKey, 0) ; remove "Numpad" if using number pad
    SendInput, %PriorKey%{Left 2}:{Right 2}
return
```

If you want to be more precise:

```
#Hotstring * ? 

::0+::
::1+::
; ...
::9+::
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   ; save Clipboard
    clipboard := ""             ; empty the clipboard
    PriorKey := SubStr(A_PriorKey, 0) ; remove "Numpad" if using number pad
    SendInput, %PriorKey%{Shift Down}{Left 4}{Shift Up} ; select the last 4 typed chars
    Send, ^c                    ; copy the selected text
    ClipWait, 1                 ; wait for the clipboard to contain data. 
    if (!ErrorLevel)            ; If NOT ErrorLevel clipwait found data on the clipboard
    {
        If ((clipboard is number) && (SubStr(clipboard, 1, 2) < 24) && (SubStr(clipboard, -1) < 60))
            Send, {Left}{Right 2}:{Right 2}
        else 
            Send, {Right}
    }
    Sleep, 300
    clipboard := ClipSaved    ; restore original clipboard
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with numbers entered via the number pad? Works great but only if using number keys that are located above the letters.

Comment: Try the edited codes.